# Is there a way to have preview active by default with SimpleMde React?

Tags: reactjs, react-md-editor

I want to render my SimpleMde by default instead of having to click the Render Option, but I cant find how to do it.

```
const markdownEditorOptions = useMemo(() => {
    const options: Options = {
      toolbar: ['preview'],
      status: false,
      renderingConfig: {
        markedOptions: {
          gfm: true,
          breaks: true,
        },
      },
    };
    return options;
  }, []);
```

This are currently my options, what I mean is a way to have the preview in the tool bar to be enabled by default.

Answer (score 0):

you can activate preview with `SimpleMDE.prototype.togglePreview`

if you need readonly mde preview, here is a hack:

```js
const mde = new SimpleMDE({
    element: document.querySelector("#profile-bio > .markdown-preview > textarea"),
    toolbar: ["preview"],
    initialValue: "Lorem **ipsum**."

});

// actiate preview mode
mde.togglePreview();
```

```css
/* hide all editor related ui, for preview only mde */
.markdown-preview > .CodeMirror,
.markdown-preview > .CodeMirror > .editor-preview {
    background-color: transparent;
    padding: 0;
}

.markdown-preview > .CodeMirror > .editor-preview {
    display: contents;
}

.markdown-preview > .CodeMirror > .CodeMirror-scroll {
    display: none;
}

.markdown-preview > .editor-toolbar {
    display: none !important;
}
.markdown-preview > .editor-statusbar {
    display: none !important;
}
```